# What is NEO4J most number of nodes we can have in NEO4J?

Tags: neo4j

I was in a page in NEO4J website about [Capabilities capacity](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-capacity.html)

And it that page it says:

> In Neo4j, data size is mainly limited by the address space of the
>   primary keys for Nodes, Relationships, Properties and
>   RelationshipTypes. Currently, the address space is as follows:
>   nodes

And it says nodes:  2^23 (~34 billion) and relationships: 2^23 (~34 billion)

**So, did I understand it correctly that we just can have 34 billions nodes or relationships?**

Answer (score 3):

Not in Neo4j 3.0:

http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity/

"Dynamic pointer compression expands Neo4j’s available address space as needed, making it possible to store graphs of any size. That’s right: no more 34 billion node limits!"

Comment: hen why there is a limit in their website docs? The link is for version 3.0.1 http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/capabilities-capacity.html

Comment: Actually the limit is 2^50 for enterprise edition https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.1/enterprise/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/store/format/highlimit/HighLimit.java#L49 I guess the docs need to be updated.